# make url_for preserve scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scope, helper

In my Rails app I need to define two different routes to some resources. I'm trying to use `scope` to have scoped and unscoped routes. Thus I defined:

```
   scope path: '(:prefix)', :prefix => /my/ do
     resources :users
   end
```

And now my users can be reached by `/my/users/:id` or by `/users/:id paths`.

The problem is that I need URL helpers to provide correct paths depending on the path I used to reach a page. I need link to `/my/users/:id/edit` when I open page using `/my/users/:id` and link to `/users/:id/edit` when I open `/users/:id`. More importantly I need correctly working forms, that use `url_for` helper to determine correct action. For the above config `url_for @user` generates `/25/users/25` (when `@user.id == 25`).

The question is how to make `url_for` preserve the scope used to reach the page?

Or maybe you can suggest different solution to allow different URLs reaching some resources and preserving paths for intuitive navigation?

Answer (score 0):

The following resolved the problem on my side:

```
get '/some_path' => 'controller#action',  somevar: 'blah'
scope path: '/my/' do
  get '/some_path' => 'controller#action', somevar:'blahblah'
end
```

Seems that if the routes share the same variable then url_for uses it to distinguish the ambiguity.